# html to exe> prevent javascript and activex security prompt in internet explorer object

Tags: javascript, html, security, offline, explorer

i have some HTML page that I've imported them in a exe file and i load them with internet explorer object . but i receive  JavaScript and ActiveX  security error whilerunning the exe file.
is it possible to sign my application to IE and prevent these prompts.?

**Note:** My application will be installed to user computer via an installation file (.msi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using gdgsoft html2exe app. I guess you should better ask in their forums, but in the security settings of internet explorer you can choose the security level ( or maybe you can use one of the other html renderers that html2exe comes with )